# Network flow as a linear/integer programming problem with special conditional constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, network-flow

Consider the classic network flow problem where the constraint is that the inflow to a vertex is equal to the sum of its outflows. Consider having a more specific constraint where the flow cannot be split between edges. The constraint is that the inflow `a` to a vertex `v` is equal to `b` (the amount that `v` has acquired from `a`) plus `c` (the outflow carried by **only** **one** of the non-visited edges of `v`).

The figure below demonstrates this in 3 mutually exclusive cases. The green  directed edge carries an inflow of value `a`. Vertex `b` takes some value of `a`, then only one of the edges (disregarding the inflow edge) carries the outflow of value `c=a-b` (illustrated in 3 cases - the red edge represents the edge carrying the outflow, the rest of the edges should have zero outflow).

[image]

Is this constraint possible to formulate under the linear/integer programming setting ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that you need a MIP formulation for that. What about the following? Assume directed arcs (this means all our flows are non-negative: $x_{i,j}\ge 0$). First write down the in-flow=out-flow balance equation:

$$ \sum_i x_{i,k} = u_k + \sum_j x_{k,j}  \> \forall k$$

Here $u_k$ is what is consumed by node $k$ (could be a variable or a coefficient; not sure from the description). Then add binary variables and constraints:

$$ \begin{array}{ll} 
   x_{k,j} \le M_{k,j} \delta_{k,j} & \forall k,j\\
   \sum_j \delta_{k,j} = 1 & \forall k \\
   \delta_{k,j} \in \{0,1\} \\
\end{array}$$
The coefficient $M_{k,j}$ should be chosen as small as possible (i.e. equal to the upperbound or capacity of arc $x_{k,j}$). In this case, instead of binary variables you could use [SOS1 sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_ordered_set) to model this (I usually choose the formulation with binary variables).

Of course depending on the network you may not need this (e.g. a shortest path problem will never split its flow). Note that this formulation allows multiple incoming flows, but only a single outgoing flow. Also I have ignored the source and the sink nodes, they may have additional in and outflow and need special treatment (the flow balance equation is slightly different for them).

Comment: Thanks! that's a great formulation of the problem!